# Defining SI units inside a \newcolumntype within a minigloss

Tags: environments, tabularx, siunitx

We want to program a `\newenvironment{minigloss}`.
Inside this minigloss we want to make a table with three columns:
parameters, explanation of the parameter, unit.
However we are not sure how to program the `\si{}` in a `\newcolumntype` for the last column.
We want to have are column take si units for the newenvironment, so we don't have to define `\si` in each individual minigloss.

Below an example of our computation:

```
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$} l< {$}}

\newcolumntype{s}{>{$\si{\collectcell l <\endcollectcell$}}} %this does not work

\newenvironment{minigloss}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
    \tabularx{0.95\linewidth}{M >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X s}%
}
{
    \endtabularx
}

\begin{flushright}
\begin{minigloss}
a & in meter & \m \\
b & in degree  & \m^3/\m/\s \\

\end{minigloss}
\end{flushright}
```

The final result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Please extend your example to a full minimal example that others can copy and test as is.

Answer (score 1):

You used the wrong syntax for `\collectcell`, the following corrects that. Also, for `siunitx` you don't necessarily need the maths mode (but you can add it, just use the commented line instead):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcolumntype{M}{>{$} l< {$}}

%\newcolumntype{s}{>{$\collectcell\si}l<{\endcollectcell$}}%this works
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\collectcell\si}l<{\endcollectcell}}% math mode not necessary

\newenvironment{minigloss}
  {%
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
    \tabularx{0.95\linewidth}{M >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X s}%
  }
  {%
    \endtabularx
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
  \begin{minigloss}
    a & in meter & \m \\
    b & in degree  & \m^3/\m/\s \\
  \end{minigloss}
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]